# How to ignore a specific bundle for optimization in asp.net BundleConfig

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, optimization, bundle

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularJs").Include(
              "~/Scripts/angular.min.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularComponents").Include(
                "~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/loading-bar.min.js"));


    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
              "~/Content/loading-bar.min.css",
              "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));

    bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
    bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*angular-route.min.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
    bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*angular-local-storage.min.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
    bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*loading-bar.min.js", OptimizationMode.Always);

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Here i want to remove this bundle (`new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularComponents")`) from optimization. I have tried the above way, but it doesn't ignore from optimization. Files are combined as well. Can anybody tell me how can i ignore this specific bundle list ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the bellow code.It will add the related script but do not minify.

```
var angularComponents = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularComponents").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/loading-bar.min.js"
                );

            bundles.Add(angularComponents);

            angularComponents.Transforms.Clear();
```

Comment: Yes. This way it is possible to skip minification of a section. That is what i expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ScriptBundle scriptBndl = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap");
    scriptBndl.Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                        "~/Scripts/respond.js"
                      );
    bundles.Add(scriptBndl);
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: If you add BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; line then it will minify the script but he does not want to minify the script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to comment out the mentioned lines below?

```
//bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularComponents").Include(
    //"~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js",
    //"~/Scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js",
    //"~/Scripts/loading-bar.min.js"));
```

Comment: Why i comment it ? I need this file, but i don't want them combine into one file.

Comment: Then you can create separate bundles or use each script group by adding them to the realated _Layout or View page..

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the scripts bundled, *don't put them in a bundle*. Am I missing something here? The sole purpose of creating bundles is to have a bunch of scripts joined together and minimized. If you don't want that, then just include the scripts directly on the page, and don't involve the bundler.

Comment: Obviously this is a way.